# C# code puzzle returns a puzzling result

Tags: c#

Jon Skeet, if you're listening, this might be of interest to you, since it's related to your code puzzle here... http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/01/14/a-tale-of-two-puzzles/

**Code**

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool? x = (true) ? null : default(bool?);
        bool? y = (true) ? x is bool? : default(bool?);

        Console.WriteLine(x);
        Console.WriteLine(y);

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

**Output**

> False

What puzzles me, is that I expected to see this...

> True

```
bool? y = (true) ? x is bool? : default(bool?);
```

since `: default(bool?)` will never be hit, why is `x is bool?` returning `false`, when it IS `bool?` ?

Comment: Maybe your are looking for *typeof* operator?

Comment: Because it's not a `bool?`  It's _null_.  A null value has no type.

Comment: using typeof would invalidate the code puzzle (not that it matters here)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first statement obviously sets the value of `x` to `null`.  The second statement checks to see if the value of `x` "is a" `bool?`.

The `is` operator does not care about the *declared* type of the variable.  It looks at the *actual* type of the object that's being evaluated.  Since `x` is set to `null`, the *value* that's passed to the `is` operator is `null`, meaning there *is no* object being referenced, and thus `is bool?` returns `false`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx):

> An `is` expression evaluates to true **if the provided expression is non-null**, and the provided object can be cast to the provided type without causing an exception to be thrown.